# WinForm: Is it possible to use the same function for multiple controls but return different results, depending on what is hovered?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hover, controls

I have a few (28) controls. Something needs to be displayed depending on what is hovered. I was wondering if there is a way I can avoid making 28 functions (one for each control hover), and maybe make only one?

Eg.
I want to replace something like this:

```
 void btn1Hover() { value = 1; }
    void btn2Hover() { value = 2; }
    ....
```

with something like:

```
 void btnsHover() { if(btn.Name= "btn1") value=1; else 2}
```

p.s sry for the code indenting. I don't know why it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works. You will see that you can select an existing function as event handler for any control. You can pick the same function for all 28 controls. The first parameter you get in this function is the sender. That's the control that you are looking for.

Comment: You answer sounds very likely to what I'm looking for, can you please give a material or anything on using the sender in a function?

Comment: Create the function, give it a try, if you have problems, ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function that makes what you want and add this function to MouseHover event of all the buttons from properties screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, using the Tag Property may be very interesting in your case

```
private void buttonMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value = ((Button)sender).Tag  

    }
```

you can assign this method to the event MouseHover of your Buttons

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about tags yet, but I understand where your going with the example. I'll mark this as useful too

Comment: thanks, I encourage you to read more about Tags and their usage, 
you can find here a first overview [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function in which you can use  Switch Statement:

```
Switch
{
  Case btn1Hover:
  break;
  Case btn2Hover:
  break
}
```